# How can I trigger re-generation of /usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@wlpXs0.service

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi-configuration, systemd, wpa-supplicant

There are standard systemd network config files for wpa_supplicant, namely `/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@wlpXs0.service`. These are generated automatically at some point, presumably by installing some package related to this.

How can I re-generate these files manually?

In my system, the files are not owned by any package. This is probably because they are generated locally, but it does make it very difficult to understand where they come from. From my package manager logs, I surmise that mine were last updated when I installed `ntp`. However, uninstalling and/or reinstalling ntp (or systemd or wpa_supplicant for that matter) does not change anything.

Reason for doing this: Modifications to the hardware can cause the device addresses (the X in `wlpXs0`) to be reassigned. In this case your systemd configuration will not be correct any more and will not find the network device.

System is: Arch Linux, kernel 5.7.6, systemd 245.6, wpa_supplicant 2.9

Answer (score 1):

In the standard Arch Linux packages, these files are not being generated *at all*. They should not exist on your system in the first place. (Additionally, no tool or package should write dynamically generated files under /usr. There are some exceptions to that, but usually generated files would show up only under /etc, /var, or /run.)

The wpa_supplicant package does ship a single `/usr/.../wpa_supplicant@.service` unit file, which acts as a template for instantiating `wpa_supplicant@interface.service` units *in memory*, but those never get written to the filesystem.

Attempting to 'systemctl enable' these virtual instances will create symlinks under `/etc/systemd/system` which will be named as in your example, but all of them point to the same template file. (And again, these symlinks would be under /etc and not under /usr/share.)